# How to make a pydantic model await an async function using PydanticMeta [FastAPI, Tortoise ORM]

Tags: python, async-await, fastapi, pydantic, tortoise-orm

I'm currently working on a personal finance api and I'm struggling on the return of some function that are async in a pydantic model.
I'm using FastApi, pydantic and Tortoise ORM.
Basicaly the aim is to return a sum of all the Budget.amount (month_base) of a given User but the problem is that this function is async and when I pass it to the PydanticMeta class as a computed field it is not awaited and hence the return value is not the right type as stated in the following errors:

> ERROR:hypercorn.error:Error in ASGI Framework
> [...]
> File "pydantic/main.py", line 573, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.from_orm
> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for User
> month_base value is not a valid float (type=type_error.float)

> /home/jon/ml-v3/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tortoise/contrib/pydantic/base.py:88: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'User.month_base' was never awaited

My code in models.py:

```
class SoftDeleteMixin:
    deleted = fields.BooleanField(default=False)
    deletion_date = fields.DatetimeField(null=True)

    def soft_delete(self):
        """
        Annotate the object as deleted and saves the deletion_date
        ---Return---
        False if the object is already deleted else True
        """
        if self.deleted:
            return False
        self.deleted = True
        self.deletion_date = datetime.today()
        return True

    @classmethod
    async def get_non_deleted(cls, user_id: int):
        return await cls.filter(Q(user_id=user_id) & Q(deleted=False))
    

class User(Model):
        id = fields.IntField(pk=True)
        gender = fields.IntEnumField(Gender, default=Gender.not_specified)
        configured = fields.BooleanField(default=False)
        start_date = fields.DatetimeField(null=True)
        email = fields.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, index=True)
        full_name = fields.CharField(max_length=50)
        password_hash = fields.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
        confirmed = fields.BooleanField(default=False)
        general_terms_and_conditions_of_sale_signed = fields.BooleanField(default=False)
        privacy_policy_signed = fields.BooleanField(default=False)
        signature_date = fields.DatetimeField(null=True)
        # One-To-Many relationships
        budgets: fields.ReverseRelation['Budget']
        origins: fields.ReverseRelation['Origin']
        long_budgets: fields.ReverseRelation['LongBudget']
        stocks: fields.ReverseRelation['Stock']
        outcomes: fields.ReverseRelation['Outcome']
        incomes: fields.ReverseRelation['Income']
        costs: fields.ReverseRelation['Cost']
        transfer: fields.ReverseRelation['Transfer']
        images: fields.ReverseRelation['Image']
    
    async def get_budgets(self):
        return await Budget.get_non_deleted(user_id=self.id).order_by('order')

    async def month_base(self) -> float:
        return sum(map(lambda budget: budget.month_budget,
                       await self.get_budgets()))
    class PydanticMeta:
        computed = ['month_base', ]
        exclude = ['password_hash',
                   'general_terms_and_conditions_of_sale_signed',
                   'privacy_policy_signed',
                   'signature_date',
                   'confirmed']
```

My code in schemas.py:

```
User = pydantic_model_creator(models.User, name='User')
UserIn = pydantic_model_creator(models.User,
                                exclude=('configured',
                                         'start_date'),
                                name='UserIn',
                                exclude_readonly=True)
```

My code in main.py:

```
async def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_schema)):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, JWT_SECRET, algorithms=['HS256'])
        user = await User.get(id=payload.get('id'))
    except:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail='Invalid username or password'
        )
    return await sch.User.from_tortoise_orm(user)
@app.get('/user', response_model=sch.User)
async def read_user(user: sch.User = Depends(get_current_user)):
    return user
```

How should I proceed to pass my month_budget field to my User schema but specify to the pydanticModel to await for its result ?
Thanks for the help !

Comment: What does `Budget.get_non_deleted` do ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on async functions, but in `get_budgets` you have `return await...` and in `month_base` you simply have `return sum(...`. Perhaps try the same thing for that second function?

Comment: @yanjost it is a custom async function to handle soft deletion in my db I'll add it's content to the post